# jQuery no carga en Github Pages

Tags: html, github

Ya he probado a cambiar las http:// que había, por https://
También probado a poner simplemente //

Y tampoco funciona.

Este es el repo: https://github.com/Onpointiscake/Onpointiscake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has cambiado el branch a `gh-pages`? te dejo un enlace a un [manual](https://devcode.la/tutoriales/publicar-tu-web-usando-github-pages/), comprueba que hayas seguido los pasos. Y en principio con poner `nombreUsuario.github.io` debería de llevarte a la página. También decirte que a veces los cambios son algo lentos, por lo que déjale hasta 10 minutos de margen.

Un saludo!

Comment: Vaya, parece que el error fue mi incapacidad para esperar! Ya se ha actualizado, gracias igualmente.